# Timer Queues - Win32 apps - period timeout problem

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, timer

I created a Timer Queue, but at the first runs of my code the timer is not reliable. After a few minutes, however, it becomes correct, even with reasonable precision. I attach the timeouts.

period of 50ms

`47
47
60
46
47
63
46
46
47
49
63
47
47
47
60
46
47
63
46
46
47
49
63
47`

after a few minutes of execution
period of 50ms

`50
50
50
50
50
50
50
49
50
50
49
49
50
49
50
49
49
50
50`

Since the timer is 'synchronized' also on the next code executions the timer is reliable.
But if I don't run the code for an hour (for example) the problem recurs.

Does anyone know the reason for this problem? 
How can I have an accurate and reliable timer from the first run?

This timer is created on a std::thread, here's my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "NativeTimer.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

static int times0;
VOID func(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    times0 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() - times0;
    std::cout << times0 << std::endl;
    times0 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}
int main()
{
    NativeTimer *t1 = new NativeTimer(50,func);
    while(1)
    {}
}
```

NativeTimer.h

```
#ifndef NATIVETIMER_H
#define NATIVETIMER_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>

class NativeTimer
{
public:
    NativeTimer(unsigned int msec,
                VOID (*func)(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired));
public:
    void stopTimer();
private:
    int startTimer(unsigned int msec,
                VOID (*func)(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired));
    int _id;
    unsigned int _msec;
    std::thread _thread;
    HANDLE gDoneEvent;
};

#endif // NATIVETIMER_H
```

NativeTimer.cpp

```
#include "NativeTimer.h"
#include <iostream>


NativeTimer::NativeTimer(unsigned int msec,
                         VOID (CALLBACK *func)(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired))
{
    _thread = std::thread(&NativeTimer::startTimer, this, msec, func);
}


int NativeTimer::startTimer(unsigned int msec,
                            VOID (CALLBACK *func)(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired))
{
    HANDLE hTimer = nullptr;
    HANDLE hTimerQueue = nullptr;

    gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);

    hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();

    CreateTimerQueueTimer( &hTimer,
                           hTimerQueue,
                           (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)func,
                           nullptr,
                           msec,
                           msec,
                           0);

    if (WaitForSingleObject(gDoneEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(gDoneEvent);
    DeleteTimerQueue(hTimerQueue);

    return 0;
}

void NativeTimer::stopTimer()
{
    SetEvent(gDoneEvent);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you share [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: okay, you can use this link for complete example, thank you
https://pastebin.com/58x1WpQx

Comment: Please post your code directly by [edit]ing the question. I (and I'm sure, many other) refrain from following links to external ressources, which will get lost soon. But your question will stay, becoming useless. -- And please try to minimize your [example].

Comment: Edited post, this example it works! 
@thebusybee

Comment: Is it possible that another process calls [`TimeBeginPeriod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) and increases the timer resolution? In any case, add a call to `TimeBeginPeriod(1)` just before you start the timer.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, and I have tried many times. But I didn't reproduce your problem, please check if there is any other codes that affect the timer queue. This is [screensnap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XWDG.png).